# Dropzone.js : Upload file without Browse dialog in php-webdriver integration tests

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, dropzone.js, facebook-php-webdriver

i am using `dropzone.js` in my project , what i want to do is add file manually to queue without opening the file browser dialogue, the dropzone is already initialized on the element with class .imageDropzone on the page and i am trying to run the following script to add the file ,

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover=false;
var myZone=Dropzone.forElement('.imageDropzone');
var fileList=$("input[accept='image/jpg,image/gif,image/png,image/jpeg']")[0].files;
fileList.name="imageUploadTestJPG.jpg";
fileList.type="image/jpeg";
fileList.size=30170,
fileList.path="http://mysite/img/imageUploadTestJPG.jpg";
fileList.mozFullPath="http://mysite/img/imageUploadTestJPG.jpg";
fileList.accept="image/jpg,image/gif,image/png,image/jpeg";

console.log(fileList);
myZone.addFile(fileList);
```

#### why am I doing this

**1**. I am working with php-webdriver and I need to test the upload functionality,

**2.** The file browser dialogue that is opened after clicking on a file type input is OS dependent, different in different OS, and I cant shift control to that window, so I wanted to skip this process of opening the file dialogue by clicking on it and want to add the file manually javascript/jquery and keeping `autoProcessFiles=true` so that as soon the file is added the upload process starts, but I am unable to solve it.

when i try to call `Dropzone.addFile()` i receive the following

> TypeError: Argument 2 of FormData.append does not implement interface
>   Blob

I event tried another way i.e

**1**. Add the file path to the file input on which the dropzone was initialized because dropzone binds an `change eventlistener` with all the `file inputs` which are initialized with dropzone and as soon the path to file is provided the `change event listener` triggers and starts uploading the file, but trying to modify the value for file input with dropzone initialized raised security exception.

**2**. Moreover the `<input type=file>` is made hidden by the `dropzone.js` script when initialized and php-webdriver does not allow to interact with hidden elements so i am stuck with this, any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done,

The problem was with the format of FileList object that was provided to the `myZone.addFile()`.If you open `dropzone.js` file and go to `Dropzone.prototype.init` function in there you will see a check

`if (this.clickableElements.length) {`

inside this check dropzone creates & configures the hidden file input and then attaches that input element  to the body `document.body.appendChild(_this.hiddenFileInput);` and right after this line dropzone adds the `change` eventlistener to file type input that was created which fires as soon as we provide the file via browse file window.

`return _this.hiddenFileInput.addEventListener("change", function() {`

When we provide the file it fires and creates the `FileList` object see

`files = _this.hiddenFileInput.files;`

if you try to log it in console `console.log(files)` you will see a FileList that is created 
`FileList { 0=File, length=1, item=item(), more...}` on clicking this object inside firebug you will see detail below

```
0          File { size=21789, type="image/png", name="1-7-2013 6-19-44 PM.png", more...}
length      1
__proto__   FileListPrototype { item=item(), @@iterator=@@iterator()}
```

now the way i was creating the filelist object the result was following

```
_removeLink -----  a.dz-remove javascrip...defined; 
accept      -----  "image/jpg,image/gif,image/png,image/jpeg"   
accepted    -----  true 
mozFullPath -----  "http://mysite/img/imageUploadTestJPG.jpg"   
name        -----  "imageUploadTestJPG.jpg" 
path        -----  "http://mysite/img/imageUploadTestJPG.jpg"   
previewElement --   div.dz-preview  
previewTemplate --- div.dz-preview  
processing    ----- true    
size                30170   
status        ----- "uploading"
type                "image/jpeg"    
upload        -----  Object { progress=0, total=30170, bytesSent=0}
xhr            XMLHttpRequest { readyState=1, timeout=0, withCredentials=false, more...}
length             0
__proto__          FileListPrototype { item=item(), @@iterator=@@iterator()}
```

Notice the index `0` on the first detail which contains the detail of the file whereas the second one which is the result of my custom built FileList object has all the details of the file on the main rather than inside the index `0`.

So to create similar object i had to first

- Obtain the blob via sending the `xmlHttpRequest` request to the image
- Specifying the response type of `arraybuffer`
- Obtain a `blob URL` for the image data.
- Assign that response to the file object and assign that to the `input.file`
- Calling the `Dropzone.addFile()`.

the complete description for the process is below and you can upload file without opening the file browse window and use `dropzone.js` with `selenium`

```
// Simulate a call to  service that can
// return an image as an ArrayBuffer.
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// Use JSFiddle logo as a sample image to avoid complicating
// this example with cross-domain issues.
xhr.open( "GET", "http://localhost/path/to/my/image.jpg", true );

// Ask for the result as an ArrayBuffer.
xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";

xhr.onload = function( e ) {
    // Obtain a blob: URL for the image data.
    var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array( this.response );
    var blob = new Blob( [ arrayBufferView ], { type: "image/jpeg" } );
    var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL( blob );

    var parts = [blob, new ArrayBuffer()];

    file = new File(parts, "imageUploadTestFile", {
        lastModified: new Date(0), // optional - default = now
        type: "image/jpeg" 
    });

    $("input[accept=\'image/jpg,image/gif,image/png,image/jpeg\']").files = [file];
    myzone = Dropzone.forElement(".imageDropzone");
    myzone.addFile(file);
};
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Nice answer, it helped me!

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped you out rokas