# Append value to input file with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an div on one side and an input type file on the other side. I wanted on click of a button, to copy the content of the div (which is an image) into to the input file. So I tried.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#mbtn').click(function(){
    $('#mfile').attr('value',$('#mdiv').html());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="mfile">
<div id="mdiv"></div>
<button id="mbtn" type="button">Clikck</button>
```

Comment: so you want to copy an image inside a input type "file"?

Comment: i did something like this way back but was a little different as it included uploading file with the dropzone.js and selenium web drivers, see here if you could use it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27785721/dropzone-js-how-to-upload-file-using-selenium-php-webdrivers

Comment: yes bro, I want on click on the button, the input file "mfile" must be filled with an image.